# Cannot resolve symbol FlutterActivity

Tags: android, flutter

I imported flutter project from github into Android Studio with 'VCS -> Checkout from Version Control'. And now I'm facing the issue: `Cannot resolve symbol FlutterActivity` in android's MainActivity.java.

I created another flutter project with `New Flutter Project` wizard. And there was no that kind of issue. The difference between the two projects was that the project from github didn't have `External Libraries/Flutter for Android/flutter.jar` whereas created from scratch one had.

I compared pubspec.yaml and build.gradle files of both projects and didn't find anything that looks like related to that dependency.

Here the pubspec.yaml of the project in question:

```
name: utopian_rocks_mobile
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.12.0
  rxdart: ^0.19.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

How that kind of dependency supposed to be handled in a flutter project?

Comment: Try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#generated-project-files-outdated

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Thanks for pointing out! There were few other issues but this one was resolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a project is created with flutter create foo several files in the ios/ and android/ sub-directories are created.

Newer Flutter versions might generate these files a bit differently and projects created with older Flutter versions might cause issues.

**Ways to fix**
Delete the `ios/` and/or `android/` directories and run `flutter create .` to re-generate these directories.

**Hint**
Custom changes will be lost and need to be re-applied. This is easiest if the project is committed to a version control system like Git.

Comment: does it make any sense to create a new project with flutter wizard first and then pull from github repo to ensure project is setup correctly?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Pull what from GitHub? Just ensure your Flutter install is up-to-date before you create a new project.

Comment: I mean, suppose I want to pull a flutter project from github to work on it on the local machine. The way I got the issue above is by using 'Checking out from Version Control' in Android studio. I suspect that it skips some steps required for generating valid flutter project. So I assumed that creating flutter project first will do all required setup. And only then pull from a repo.

Comment: If the project was created with an older Flutter version my answer is basically **the** solution to your problem until the Flutter team improves automatic updates of generated files. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#generated-project-files-outdated links to related issues.

Answer (score 0):

create a new flutter project using android studio you can not find the FlutterActivity class because of android studio can not find the flutter SDK path .

Answer (score 0):

You could try linking android folder as a gradle project. Right click on the android/build.gradle file and select link as gradle project. Then you can refresh dependencies in the gradle tool window.
[image]