# Cannot resolve symbol 'FlutterActivity'

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin

I just created a new Flutter project, and I already have errors. It says "**Cannot resolve symbol 'FlutterActivity'**" in MainActivity.java

***(Why???)***

There is no easy to find answer online. All of them, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008894/cannot-resolve-symbol-flutteractivity), are unrelated.

Also, in a project I created with Kotlin support I get a similar error in MainActivity.kt: "**Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity**"

Comment: Could you solve this problem? It's still exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flutter with stable version .. just change it to Dev version then try to build you app again.

The reason you are mentioned in the link.

Comment: Then in terminal execute this commends

flutter clean
to clean the old build.

second commend flutter pub cache repair

Comment: How do you delete android and iso directories?

Comment: I know... there is no option to delete.

Comment: I've added an answer to the link you have posted as that is more relevent.

Answer (score 0):

when we want to use methodChannel and use kotlin/java class
to open mainActivity use below way (don't open android in dart), in flutter project File/open/root of our project / select android, then open it new window and wait for its configuration to finish and write your code in this space